# How to expand this C++ template parameter package

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, metaprogramming

I want to expand the template parameter package into a 2-dimensional array, but I don't know how to achieve it

Because the elements of the matrix class are usually floating point decimals, but this is only supported by the syntax after C++20

```
template<int Row, int Col, typename T = float>
struct MATRIX
{
    template<T... Args>
    MATRIX(Args... nums) : aNumbers{ (nums, 0)... }// this is error
    {
        //aNumbers = { (nums, 0)... };
    }

    T aNumbers[Row][Col];
```

I tried several syntaxes, but none of them compiled. I want to achieve a constructor with variable length template parameters

Comment: How do you want this to work? To be able to pass `Row*Col` arguments to initialize every argument? Then what's `,0` doing in there?

Comment: "but this is only supported by the syntax after C++20" unclear what you mean. A matrix can have floating point elements long before c++20. I suppose you refer to floating point non type template arguments?

Comment: First things first, `Args` is a non-type template parameter so `MATRIX(Args... nums)` is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide whether you want the elements be non-type template arguments (this would require c++20) or ordinary arguments to the constructor. The latter is rather straightforward:

```
template<int Row, int Col, typename T = float>
struct MATRIX
{
    template <typename...X>
    MATRIX(X... nums) : aNumbers{ nums... }
    {

    }

    T aNumbers[Row][Col];
};

int main() {
    MATRIX<3,3,double> m{1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,8.,9.};
}
```

Only to make sure that `X...` equals `T`, something extra is needed. Though, one step at a time, and I consider this beyond the scope of the question.

In your code:

```
template<T... Args>
MATRIX(Args... nums)
```

`Args` is a non-type template argument for the constructor, hence `Args...nums` makes no sense.

Comment: thank you, This code will not automatically convert types. It makes "Compiler Error C2397    conversion from 'int' to 'T' requires a narrowing conversion".

Answer (score 1):

> `MATRIX(Args... nums) : aNumbers{ (nums, 0)... }`// this is error

The problem is that `Args` is a non-type template parameter(variadic) and so you cannot use it as a type in the function parameter list. In other words, `MATRIX(Args... nums)` is invalid syntax.